# Protocol Buffer import resolution

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protoc

Before reading through this rather long question, I've raised a bug https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/1103.

The documentation for Proto [Packages and Name Resolution](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#services) states

> You can use definitions from other .proto files by importing them. To
>   import another .proto's definitions, you add an import statement to
>   the top of your file.

My `example.proto` depends on [annotations.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/annotations.proto) to [transcode HTTP/JSON to gRPC](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding). This is a trivial example, but note I use the import path from the [googleapis/google/api](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/api) Git repo (i.e. `google/api/annotations.proto`):

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

message MyExample {
  // Message definition here.
}
```

Note, [annotations.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/annotations.proto) depends on [http.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto) - they are siblings in the same package ([googleapis/google/api](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/api))

[image]

My local project directory contains three .proto files:

1. `example.proto`
2. `google/api/annotations.proto`
3. `google/api/http.proto`

...or as a tree:

```
|____google
| |____api
| | |____annotations.proto
| | |____http.proto
|____example.proto
```

The target (or, 'out') directories are added too, ready to receive the generated python files:

```
|____generated_pb2
| |____google
| | |____api
```

There for my complete project directory structure is:

- `example.proto`
- `google/api/annotations.proto`
- `google/api/http.proto`
- `generated_pb2/google/api`

...or as a tree:

```
|____example.proto
|____google
| |____api
| | |____annotations.proto
| | |____http.proto
|____generated_pb2
| |____google
| | |____api
```

With this in place I can compile my protos (formatting added for readability):

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc
  --python_out=generated_pb2
  --grpc_python_out=generated_pb2
  -I ~/protoc/include/google/protobuf
  -I /google/api
  example.proto
```

Breaking this down:

- `generated_pb2` - Destination for generated python files and gprc files.
- `~/protoc/include/google/protobuf` - Location of common protos shipped with protoc binary, needed since [annotations.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/annotations.proto) depends on [google/protobuf/descriptor.proto](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto).
- `google/api` - Location of `annotations.proto` and `http.proto`

This compiles `example.proto` giving:

- `generated_pb2/example_pb2.py`
- `generated_pb2/example_pb2_gprc.py`

However the first line of `generated_pb2/example_pb2.py` imports the generated files for `annotations.proto`:

```
from google.api import annotations_pb2 as google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2
```

This file doesn't exist. No problem, I'll compile `annotations.proto` separately:

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc
  --python_out=generated_pb2/google/api
  --grpc_python_out=generated_pb2/google/api
  -I ~/protoc/include/google/protobuf
  -I google/api annotations.proto
```

Breaking this down:

- `generated_pb2/google/api` - Destination for generated python files and gprc files.
- `~/protoc/include/google/protobuf` - Location of common protos shipped with protoc binary, needed since [annotations.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/annotations.proto) depends on [google/protobuf/descriptor.proto](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto).
- `google/api` - Location of `http.proto` upon which `annotations.proto` depends.

Unfortunately I get an error at this point:

```
google/api/http.proto: File not found.
annotations.proto: Import "google/api/http.proto" was not found or had errors.
annotations.proto:30:3: "HttpRule" is not defined.
```

I guess this is because `annotations.proto` looks for `http.proto` in `google/api`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package google.api;

import "google/api/http.proto";
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
```

However it's unclear how this dependency is resolved.  `protoc --help` documents the `-I` flag:

```
-IPATH, --proto_path=PATH   Specify the directory in which to search for
                            imports.  May be specified multiple times;
                            directories will be searched in order.  If not
                            given, the current working directory is used.
```

How can `http.proto` upon which `annotations.proto` depends, be resolved?

Comment: The thing in your "import" is simply composed with all of the -I paths in turn until a match (exactly one) is found. Simple as that really. And onwards it goes - so if they "import", the same thing happens again. From memory, it isn't relative to the individual .proto - it is relative to the -I parameters.

Comment: @marc-gravell - it appears it is relative. I've updated my question explaining why I think this, but briefly: `google/api/http.proto` cannot be found when included from `google/api/annotations.proto`

Comment: Raised a bug for this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/1103

Answer (score 1):

as i was trying the same thing as you do, i came up with a possible solution using a [Makefile](https://github.com/laidback/example-grpc/blob/master/Makefile) to create the appropriate files.
Because i was testing with python, i installed the grpc python package and used protoc through python instead of using it directly, but the input and outcome should be the same though.

General protobuf flags used in every **protoc** call:

```
GRPC_FLAGS := \
    -I. \
    -I/usr/local/include \
    -I$(GOPATH)/src \
    -I$(GOPATH)/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis
```

#### Source generation

Source code specific flags:

```
CLIENT_FLAGS := \
    --proto_path=./protos \       <-- This is where my *.proto live
    --python_out=grpctest/client \
    --grpc_python_out=grpctest/client
```

Call **protoc** to generate project specific protocol from your *.proto

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc $(CLIENT_FLAGS) $(GRPC_FLAGS) protos/*.proto
```

#### Annotation generation

Annotation specific flags:

```
CLIENT_GW_FLAGS := \
    --python_out=grpctest/client \
    --grpc_python_out=grpctest/client
```

Call **protoc** to generate annotation specific files:

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc $(CLIENT_GW_FLAGS) $(GRPC_FLAGS) google/api/annotations.proto
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc $(CLIENT_GW_FLAGS) $(GRPC_FLAGS) google/api/http.proto
```

#### Final Filesystem Structure

```
├── client.py
├── config.yml
├── file
├── google
│   └── api
│       ├── __pycache__
│       ├── annotations_pb2.py
│       ├── annotations_pb2_grpc.py
│       ├── http_pb2.py
│       └── http_pb2_grpc.py
├── grpctest_pb2.py
└── grpctest_pb2_grpc.py
```

Comment: Hi this worked for me in generating the files. But my transcoding grpc gateway's REST endpoint isn't working. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `pip install googleapis-common-protos`.
I encountered the same error and solved it using this method.